# Reference to control of TableLayoutPanel inside split container

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I reference to `Datagridview` control inside `TableLayoutPanel` which is inside `SplitContainer Panel1` of my form ? I need to hide this `Datagrid` in code from another form.

so, design is : Form -->Split Container--> TableLayoutPanel --> Datagridview

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `I need to hide this Datagrid in code from another form` or you could add a method to the form like `HideTheDGV()` call it and let the form handle its own controls

Comment: Hi Plutonix. I'm struggling with this one - let me explain. 1st, I have a Form1 where I display records in datagridview, before that datagrid is visible=false. 2nd, when datagrid has some records I open Form2, and from here I have to determine If datagrid is visible=true. Problem is that "Form1.Datagridview1.Visible=True" doesn't return anything, I think because It references to Form1 class AND not opened Form1. What can I do to reference Opened Form1, considering I need to hold this state,because I reopen Form2 and need this Opened Form1 value again?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the `DataGridView` with the designer you can simply call it by `FormReference.DataGridViewName`.

You just have to make sure your `GenerateMember` attribute in the designer is set to `True`, which is its `Default Value` and the modifier ist set to something that allows public access.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one problem. In default, TableLayout is visible=False. After click on a button It becomes visible. Then after click in Form2 this doesn't work "If Form1.DataGridView1.Visible = True Then" - If I change to visible=false, code works. WHY ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Somehow code recognizes only visible=false, but It's not, I can see datagridview. I Don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, and It's not so simple as I thought.

1. There is not an 'automatic form collection' in VB.NET.

If the control is on Form1, then when you open Form2, it needs to have
a way of finding the Open version of Form1. Just referring to Form1 does
not get a reference to the Open Form1, just to the Form1 class.

So, Form2 needs a variable that refers to the open Form1:

```
  Public OpenedForm1 as Form1
```

Then to open Form2, Form1 needs to have:

```
Dim f as new Form2
f.OpenedForm1 = Me
f.show
```

Then Form2 would reference the control on the Form1 that opened it as:

```
Me.OpenedForm1.NameOfControl
```

If anybody has any better wat of doing this, please let me know - I don't like It pretty much.

Comment: `There is not an 'automatic form collection' in VB.NET`  There is, but it can forget forms on occasion: `Application.OpenForms()`.  It is better to hold onto form references in your code.

Comment: I tried this too, but how to check with it control that you need ? As I'm aware you can only check if form is opened this way.